# Get the date for custom day but current month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on some reporting module, where I need to implement the logic which gets a date as below cases -

My table :-

| Id | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 22 |
| 4 | 29 |

Now I have to write a query to get result as below -

Case 1- If current date (GETDATE()) is 2022-9-5 00:00:00.000

| result |
| --- |
| 2022-9-8 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-9-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-9-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-9-29 00:00:00.000 |

Case 2- If current date (GETDATE()) is 2022-9-16 00:00:00.000

| result |
| --- |
| 2022-10-8 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-10-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-9-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-9-29 00:00:00.000 |

Note : The query should work with any month / year.

Answer (score 1):

```
select dateadd(day, day, eomonth(getdate(), case when day < datepart(day, getdate()) then 0 else -1 end)) as result
from   t
```

| result |
| --- |
| 2022-10-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-10-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-09-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-09-29 00:00:00.000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2KccD9D_?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

Some DATEADD willhep, as you first need to know, the first daty of the next month and then you can add the das from your table

The moth seledcted will be determined if the day of the Selct run is smaller than the day in the table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ([Id] int, [Day] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    ([Id], [Day])
VALUES
    (1, 8),
    (2, 14),
    (3, 22),
    (4, 29)
;
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT getdate()
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 2022-09-20 18:55:21.917 |

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, [Day] -1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+
  (CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) < [Day] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 0))
FROM  table1
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 2022-10-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-10-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-09-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-09-29 00:00:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsW59_P8)

Answer (score -1):

An IF ELSE is probably what you need

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

So if the day is greater than the day in the other table, add one month to the date.